# CPU bound process going to 0% CPU when minimize in Windows

Tags: windows, process, cpu-usage, taskmanager, sigint

I have a CPU bound process running in cmd on Windows. When I minimize the cmd window, the process will eventually reduce to 0% CPU utilization (according to the Task Manager). When I restore the cmd window, it stays at 0% CPU until I hit Ctrl-C sending a SIGINT to the console.

Any idea why this is happening? Is there a Windows setting that turns this behavior off?

I'm running the program on an HP laptop that is plugged in. The code for the program can be found on my GitHub: https://github.com/Mathhead200/Molecular-Spintronics-Research-Project/blob/master/MSD%20Research%20Project%20-%20Latest%20Development%20Version/src/metropolis.cpp